# How to auto populate fields from an excel spreadsheet into a web database

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-server

I'm trying to figure out a way to create a webbased table that contains consolidated information, obtained from multiple excel spreadsheets. Currently we do a Vlookup function in excel and match the required fields with the values given. So for example:

Product ABC requires the following information:

SKU
RSP
COST
QTY SOLD
QTY IN STOCK
..etc

Each of those respective values are stored in different excel sheets so sheet 1 will have product ABC, SKU, and RSP; sheet 2 SKU, COST, QTY SOLD, etc... The common factor between all the spreadsheets are the SKU numbers.

Essentially we want to be able to match the product ABC with it's corresponding sku, cost etc.

The question is, how would I go about doing it? I understand the php aspect of calling variables but I think the biggest challenge I have is structuring the database (can be in either MSSQL or MYSQL). Any ideas on how to set up the database?

Update:

Thanks for the response those links were very helpful! How do I effectively use primary and foreign keys to make sure this works. If I have an end result which is a table called "consolidated" how can I make sure that table pulls the correct lines and matches them? The skus are not in any particular order so will sql automatically know which ones to match with what because of their defined PK/FKs?

```
table 1    table2     table 3    consolidated table
SKU        SKU        SKU         SKU  RSP    STATUS
QTY        RSP        COST        QTY  COST
DES       QTY-SOLD    STATUS      DES  QTY SOLD
```

Comment: updated my post to answer your new questions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you'll need PHP to read your excel file.

You can do 2 things:

1. convert all your excel files to csv
2. use something like this http://code.google.com/p/php-excel-reader/downloads/detail?  name=php-excel-reader-2.21.zip&can=2&q= (examples inside the rar)

I propose you make an empty database table with all the intel of your products as colums (so all the stuff you've typed), with the SKU numbers as index.

If you use csv, you can use this: http://www.daniweb.com/web-development/php/threads/119197

If you want to do a batch upload, I would use a loop while scanning the desired folder on your server.

When you import, you'll need to ask mySQL if your product already exists, if so: UPDATE, else, INSERT INTO your created table:

```
if(mysql_num_rows("SELECT SKU FROM yourtable WHERE SKU = $sku") == 1) {
       $result = mysql_query("UPDATE yourtable SET cost = $cost, in_stock = $in_stock WHERE SKU=$sku) OR die(mysql_error());
} else {
       $result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO yourtable (SKU, cost, in_stock) VALUES ($sku, $cost, $in_stock) OR die(mysql_error());
}
```

Afterwards you can select, update, calculate,... with your stuff as much as you want, best check a reference guide for more intel (http://dev.mysql.com)

UPDATE to the posted update

Comparing different tables is easy, but you'll first need to understand the SQL JOIN concept. You can look it all up here: http://mysqljoin.com/

A 'JOIN' (probably INNER JOIN) will compare your tables on a desired key en give you a combined result for this key. Afterwards you can insert everything in your new table.

Answer (score 0):

You need to look into data normalization.  The concept has been around for many years, and is well documented and thought out.  Here is an introduction:

http://www.agiledata.org/essays/dataNormalization.html